# Using 3rd Party ADTs (GLib, sys/queue.h etc.) with C

Tags: c

I think I need a linked list ADT for my project, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a defacto implementation for C.

2 options that seem to crop up more often on Google are use of sys/queue.h and the GTK+ GLib stuff

I definitely don't think it makes any sense for me to try and reinvent the wheel and write them myself.

I am currently developing under linux with the GNU tool chain - would I potentially be making a rod for my own back if I had to port to Windows at a later date and had embedded these libraries into my code?

The GLib stuff looks very nice with a friendly web site with good documentation. Could this be thought of as the C++ STL (or possibly Boost) equivalent for C?

To summarise, I want to reuse code, but I want to resue the *right* code.

Comment: `GLib` is a good option with nice documentation as you have found out. If you are looking for linked list, the linux kernel has [a very good](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) [implementation](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.6/include/linux/list.h) which I guess you can reuse.

Comment: So I wouldn't be making a grave error with any of these three options?

Comment: I guess not. But you have to consider that - 1. If you use `GLib` there is an additional library dependency, if you have no issue then fine, 2. If you use sys/queue.h, all the code is in the header so you can start using it with just inclusion of header file, 3. If you want to use kernel code, I guess a little bit of copying from the source will be there. Finally, see what fits your bill the best and use that :) ... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is *no* "right code" available for reuse. If you don't mind its bulkiness and slow implementation, GLib is a good choice. Since it uses autoconf build system, you will also find it painful to compile it under windows.